# Single Page website with CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, layout, single-page-application

I'm currently working on a single-page scrollable website (5 pages displaying as a single page) using CakePHP. I have worked on each controller action and everything runs well. I have one layout for the entire app and a view for each action. My challenge is finding a way to load the view of each action without reloading the page inside the layout. Should I just put all the view content inside the layout (without echoing $content_for_layout) or could there be a better way to do it?

Comment: You should use ajax in such case. JsHelper will help you to achieve the same.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the `div` you want to update has the id `#content`:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"http://yourdomain.com/controller/action",
    context:document.body,
    dataType:"html",
    data:{id:123}, // in case you need to pass some params
    success:function(data){
        $("#content").html(data);
    }
})
```

The action must return the HTML you want to display inside that div. If you want to have each pags loaded in different div's, you will have to create one div for each page and call AJAX for each one.

When the page is loaded for the first time, you can just pull the data for whatever default action you defined. Then, when you want to change the content, just call AJAX.